# Pass values from php file to a html file.

Tags: php, html

Html form **submits** data to a php. Php loads it into a database and **passes** on the data (in this case *usr* ) to a html document( **resultpg.html** ).
I need the html document to say *"Hi NameOfUser,"*.

The snippet from the page containing html form:

```
<form class="login-form" action="/form.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="usr" placeholder="username"/>
<input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="password"/>
<button type=submit form="form1" value="submit">login</button>
```

I have redirected my **form.php** to open the html like:

```
if ($connect->query($query) === TRUE) {
header( 'Location: resultpg.html' );

} else {
echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $connect->error;
}
```

Comment: you can't output phpvariable into html page. your page must have `.php` extension

Comment: *"I need the html document to say "Hi NameOfUser,"."* - If I understood that correctly, you'd need to instruct your server to treat `.html` files as PHP; is that what the question is about?

Comment: @AlivetoDie *"you can't output phpvariable into html page. your page must have .php extension"*-  Not necessarily and I think you know it ;-) See my above comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- we do find examples in mail and social websites. Then how do we achieve that ?

Comment: I've closed the question; that's what this is about.

Comment: @Imacoder those two are totally different animals than what you're working with.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm running my scripts on wampserver on windows and **AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm** didn't help. I'm getting parse errors when I paste in my php script after I added it. Any help ?

Comment: @Imacoder If you're getting parse errors, update your post so I/others can see if there's anything wrong and what the `.htaccess` file looks like.

Comment: @Imacoder and please, if you're going to update your post, don't overwrite your original and mark it under it and as an edit.